# How can I print key and value of a dictionary together in a single print() function as in the given code?Error : NameError: name 'Key' is not defined

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

```
dict = {"Pond":"A Lake",
    "Lake":"A Pond",
    "Book":"Bunch of Pages",
    "Chaddi":"The Undies"
}

for key in dict:
    print(f"{Key}:{dict[key]}")
```

Comment: No, it *doesn't* show the error

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly capitalized the letter k. You wrote `Key`. Use `key`.

If `d` is your dictionary (you should not use `dict` as the name of your dictionary):

```
for key in d:
    print(f"{key}:{d[key]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has already solved your mistake.

Here I did other alternative solutions, and more understandable.

```
for key, value in dict.items():
   print(key,":",value)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things. First you simply misspelled the word key, as answered by @oda. Fix that capital k in the print function and your code will work.

Second, don't call a dictionary `dict`, since `dict` is already a function in python:

```
d = dict()
```

creates a new empty dictionary.

If you create a variable named `dict` you'll overshadow the `dict` function and you'll probably get some error sooner or later.